# How to filter gradle when copying files? If token starts with "Tel-" and ends with "-Tel" replace token with V2

Tags: gradle, ant

**Gradle Script**

```
copy {
    from 'src/com/comcast/telescope/Telescope.java'
    into 'dist/com/comcast/telescope'
include '**/*.java'
 }
```

**Ant script**

```
     <copy file="${src.dir}/com/comcast/telescope/Telescope.java" toFile="${dist.dir}/com/comcast/telescope/Telescope.java">
        <filterset begintoken="Tel-" endtoken="-Tel">
            <filter token="IntVer" value="${Interface-Version}" />
        </filterset>
```

I got the top part to copy the file, but I'm stuck on filtering the file when copying. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a call to `filter` in your `CopySpec`.

Based on the original Ant script, you need:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

copy {
    from 'src/com/comcast/telescope/Telescope.java'
    into 'dist/com/comcast/telescope'
    include '**/*.java'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, beginToken:'Tel-', endToken:'-Tel', tokens: [IntVer: interfaceVersion])
 }
```

This uses [ReplaceTokens](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) to replace the literal text `Tel-IntVer-Tel` in `Telescope.java` with the value of `interfaceVersion` as it is copied from `src/com/comcast/telescope` to `dist/com/comcast/telescope`

Please note that in my example you will need to set the `interfaceVersion` property somewhere, like in `gradle.properties` or in an [`ext` block.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) Lastly, I believe that the `include` is unnecessary, as only one file is being copied, yielding:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

copy {
    from 'src/com/comcast/telescope/Telescope.java'
    into 'dist/com/comcast/telescope'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, beginToken:'Tel-', endToken:'-Tel', tokens: [IntVer: interfaceVersion])
 }
```